# Prove that function is smooth

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, derivatives

There is a function:

$V(n) = \sum_{i=1}^\infty  f(b_i(n))b_i^{'}(n)- f(a_i(n))a_i^{'}(n)$,

where $f$,$b$ and $a$ are $C^\infty$ smooth functions.

I know that we can prove that the function $V(n)$ is also smooth under some assumptions.

I SUGGEST THE NEXT SOLUTION

As I understand we should take

$V^{'}(n) = \sum_{i=1}^\infty  f^{'}(b_i(n))b_i^{'}(n)^2+f(b_i(n))b_i^{''}(n)- f^{'}(a_i(n))a_i^{'}(n)^2-f(a_i(n))a_i^{''}(n)$,

where $f^{'}$ exists, $b^{''}$ and $a^{''}$ should also be smooth.

MY QUESTION: Can somebody check this logic and help me?

I will really appreciate your help!

Comment: You need more information on the functions $f,b_i,a_i$ to justify this result. You don't even know that the series for $V'(n)$ converges (even assuming that the series for $V(n)$ does). By the way, you calculated the derivatives of the terms incorrectly, for instance the first term should be $f'(b_i(n))b'_i(n)^2$.

Comment: Thank you, you are right, but in my case the problem is that I don'thave a lot of information about $f,b_i$ and$ a_i$ so I can do only assumptions...  It seems that we can conclude that $V^{'}$ converges uniformly if  $\sum_{i=1}^\infty  f^{'}(b_i(n))b_i^{'}(n)^2+f(b_i(n))b_i^{''}(n)- f^{'}(a_i(n))a_i^{'}(n)^2-f(a_i(n))a_i^{''}(n)=s(n)$ and $\forall \epsilon>0$, $k\geq N(\epsilon)$ so that $|\sum_{i=1}^k  f^{'}(b_i(n))b_i^{'}(n)^2+f(b_i(n))b_i^{''}(n)- f^{'}(a_i(n))a_i^{'}(n)^2-f(a_i(n))a_i^{''}(n)-s(n)|<\epsilon$